# Issue with Screen after installing ubuntu 17.04

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, monitor

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.04, replacing Windows. This was my first Ubuntu installation everything went smoothly except that my screen is not properly aligned at the edges:

[image: photograph of my monitor]

How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the resolution of the Monitor? What is the resolution in <system setting> <Displays>?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command. The screen resolution is wrong.

Comment: Use the monitors menu to calibrate the screen. Just touch the bottom side of the monitor a bit left of the power-LED and then choose `Auto` with another single touch under the `Auto`-option. That should solve this.